# Getting error when using axios POST

Tags: javascript, axios

My url, headers and body data are defined as:

```
var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer 12345',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }

var data = {
  'password': '123456',
  'ver': '1',
  'time': '1534494857045'
}
```

I am calling `axios` by:

```
axios.post(url, data, headers)
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(error => {
  if (error.response) {
    console.log(error.response.data);
    console.log(error.response.status);
    console.log(error.response.headers);
  } else if (error.request) {
    console.log(error.request);
  } else {
    console.log('Error', error.message);
  }
  console.log(error.config);
});
```

I am getting a `500` error from the server. Other apps calling the same server works fine. I even tried this out in Postman and it works. What am I doing wrong in `axios`?

Comment: You should find out what the server error is first. Then you can use that information to fix the request.

Comment: @Quentin I can't. The server works other apps. This data also works through Postman. There is something in the JS code which is causing the error.

Comment: Yes, something about the JS is causing the error but figuring out how to fix it starts by **knowing what the error is**.

Comment: @Quentin It's not my server. I can't ask them.

Comment: I think you have to check this link https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1143 maybe it can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, sadly, an educated guess because a MCVE was not provided.

See the [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format) for axios:

> By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON. To send data in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format instead, you can use one of the following options.

You are setting a `Content-Type` header which claims you are sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, but you haven't done any of the things that the documentation suggests to generate data in that format.

Comment: Yes, I had to `stringify` the data.